# Convert DataFrame to Custom nested Json

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a Dataform as below:
[image: dataframe]

I need to convert it to the following JSON format:

```
                {"tags": [ {"prj": "Retail",
                   "db": "Sales_Db",
                   "tbl":'COUNTRY',
                   "typ": "table",
                   "fields": {
                   "con": {
                      "type": "boolean",
                      "value": "yes"
                   },
                   "own": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "value": "Ravi"
                   }
                 }
                },
                {   
                   
                   "prj": "Finance",
                   "db": "rev_db",
                   "tbl":'rev_tbl',
                   "typ": "table",
                   "fields": {
                   "con": {
                      "type": "boolean",
                      "value": "no"
                   },
                   "own": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "value": "Srikanth"
                   }
                 }
                }
                ]
            }
```

I tried few answers from the Stack Overflow, but could not able to achieve the same format.

Any help on how I convert this dataframe to JSON?

Comment: You might want to check this out: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: provide data as text

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A Stack Overflow search for [`[python] dataframe to json`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+dataframe+to+json) gives more than 4600 results. Are you really sure none of these posts answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend re-formatting your DataFrame, creating new columns **con & own**, which will be aggregated dictionaries from `field, value, & type.`

You can then group your DataFrame on `['prj', 'db', 'tbl', 'typ']` and aggregate the **con & own** columns into a new column, **fields**.

Finally, use `df.to_dict(orient='records')` to convert your df to a dictionary.